# Reference for an identity from Abramowiz and Stegun

Tags: laplace-transform

I am curious as to where [this identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.23#E6) was originally obtained. Any suggestions?

$$
\frac{1}{\mathop{\Gamma}\nolimits\!\left(1+2\mu\right)2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^%
{(0+)}e^{zt+\frac{1}{2}t^{-1}}t^{\kappa}\mathop{M_{\kappa,\mu}}\nolimits\!%
\left(t^{-1}\right)dt=\frac{z^{-\kappa-\frac{1}{2}}}{\mathop{\Gamma}
\nolimits\!\left(\frac{1}{2}+\mu-\kappa\right)}\mathop{I_{2\mu}}\nolimits\!%
\left(2\sqrt{z}\right)
$$

Comment: It was easy to copy the MathML code in the link...